# How do processes share CPU in data intensive operations in EC2?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pm2

I'm performing a data intensive operation in EC2. I have a table of 50 million rows, and I'm analyzing the relationship between those rows to build clusters of similar data.

At my current speeds, it should be done within 40 hours or so. In order to reach this speed, I distributed my operations between different processes (using `pm2` in node).

**Are the processes truly independent from one another?** When I browse the logs, I often find that if one process is particularly CPU-heavy, the other processes seem to wait until the busy process finishes.

When the operations are quick, the logs look like this:

```
Process 1 | started task
Process 2 | started task
Process 1 | completed task
Process 2 | completed task
```

But when a task is heavy on Process 1, the logs look more like this:

```
Process 1 | started task (waiting a long time...)
Process 1 | completed task
Process 2 | started task
Process 2 | completed task
```

It's as if a particularly CPU-heavy operation stole the mojo from the other processes, making me feel that the processes are not independent from one another after all.

Though the code-base itself is pretty large, here is a simplified version of it (as was requested in the comments):

```
// pm2 launches processes with this method
async eachProcessStartsWithThisMethod () {

  // set up Redis listener using Bull
  queue.process(job => async {
     await cpuHeavyMethod(job.data.id)
  })

}
async cpuHeavyMethod (jobId) {
  // pull data from sources including MySQL, Redis and Elasticache
  // analyze the data using nested for-loops
  // bulk update/insert into MySQL based on responses
}
```

Here is an example of the CPU usage of the last 3 hours (on an instance that runs 13 processes):

[image: CPU usage on EC2 from 13 different processes]

Here is the associated pm2 list:

[image]

And here is a snapshot from `htop`:

[image: htop processes from 13 different processes]

Are EC2 processes just an illusion? Where did my picture go wrong?

Comment: What particular [type of EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) are you running?

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I'm running a t2.xlarge

Comment: I'm starting to understand that maybe all processes are using the same event-loop, meaning that longer operations will be hogging the CPU until they are done. Is that true?

Comment: Separate node.js processes do bot share the same event loop.  But separate requests inside the same node.js process do share the same event loop.

Comment: I would think that part of your issue would be how much CPU your EC2 instance gets.  If yoy are bottlenecked in a database on the same CPU, that could also factor in.

Comment: Do you mean that maybe I'm using up all of the CPU in my instance? The percent CPU utilized never exceeds 20%. Could it be that I can limit how much of the CPU can be allocated to each process?

Comment: Can you show us some code?  We do a lot better with actual code than purely theoretical questions.

Comment: With a t2.large, you get up to 4 CPUs so you should have plenty for two separate node.js processes to run completely independently on their own.  I would wonder if they have some shared resource such as a database that perhaps they are gated by?

Comment: If your CPU utilization *really* doesn't exceed 20%, then CPU allocation among processes is the wrong question.  If you are not familiar with utilities like `top` and `htop` then you need to familiarize yourself with them now.  You're stabbing in the dark, without this information.

Comment: Keep in mind t2 instances only offer a certain baseline performance. For t2.xlarge that's 90% out of 400%, which would translate to ~22,5% if you count all four CPUs as 100%.

Comment: @jfriend00 - You're right that the processes are all sharing some other resources (like MySQL, Redis, and Elasticache), and that maybe I can find the bottlenecks there and not anywhere else. I wasn't sure how to best show the code (it's a pretty large project by this point), but I added the outlines of my setup as well as snapshots of my CPU usage. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, I added some more snapshots about the CPU usage. Are you thinking that maybe distributing my heavy-CPU operations into different processes may not be what I should be going for?

Comment: @Adam I'm thinking CPU isn't the problem.  It looks like they could be waiting on something else.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I think 80% of the jobs are not CPU-heavy, but 20% of the jobs could require up to 5 minutes of pure processing (just going through the nested for-loops, etc.). Is it standard to use a different architecture to handle that?

Comment: @Adam unless something has changed (or my memory has failed me), `htop` on a a t2.xlarge should only show 4 processors, not 16.  Are you sure that's what you're running?  If so, please check the CPU Credit Balance metric to verify that you have > 60 CPU credits in your balance (or that you have enabled the t2 unlimited feature).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It shows that I have 144 CPU Credits on this instance, and I'm pretty sure that all 12 processors are running because pm2 logs logs data from all processes. Is it common to use a distributed processor approach to process tasks that may or may not be heavy on the CPU?